# jpg, png image positioning problems

Tags: floats

I have two figures in a row. One is png another is jpg. I thought the image type does not matter, at the end it seems like it does.

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{./images/DepositModel.png}
    \caption{Трехмерное представление модели месторождения.}
    \label{fig:3d_deposit_model}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{./images/DepositModelProjection.jpg}
    \caption{Трехмерное представление продольной проекции модели месторождения.}
    \label{fig:3d_deposit_model_projection}
\end{figure}
```

As a result image 2 is on image 1 and no caption for image 1.

I tried `H` instead of `ht!`. Now they are far away (about 10 pages) from the text and the second is positioned exactly after the first, the first does not have caption.

I have some .pdf images and I replace these ones with pdf. As a result everything is fine.

I remove width argument from both includegraphics and now it is fine, but images are huge and they goes out of pages. Then I put scale argument and the result again is awful, the images is put on each other.

Only when I converted png and jpg to pdf it is displayed fine. Why what is wrong with LaTeX (last distribution of texlive for windows, xelatex).

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Can you reproduce the problem with the standard images from the `mwe` package? If so, that would make it easier for others to diagnose.